# Why do constant names appear in compiled binaries/shared libraries?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, obfuscation, elf

I'm building a library in CMake which has some constants within a private header. When I compile in `Release` config, eg `-O3 -DNDEBUG` and run `strings` on the output, these constants appear in the output. The names of these constants reveal some implementation details that I'd like to hide if possible.

Here's a minimal project example that demonstrates the problem:

**private.h**

```
#pragma once

const int MY_CONSTANT = 42;
```

**lib.c**

```
#include "private.h"

extern int get_mask(void)
{
  return MY_CONSTANT ^ 3;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(dummylib)

add_library(mylib SHARED lib.c)
```

Build and show strings output:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. && cmake --build . --config Release -- VERBOSE=1 && strings libmylib.so | grep MY
MY_CONSTANT
```

Is there some additional switch I can use to hide this information?

Comment: Despite the name, that is not a constant. Without the `static` keyword, it's a global variable. With the `static` keyword, it's a file-scope variable. Either way, it's a variable. If you want a constant whose name won't appear in an output file, use a `#define`.

Comment: I corrected the const mistake, the actual library has the `const` keyword on all of these.

Comment: @Mat it seems like the CMake `Release` build type handles this implicitly, but I'll be sure to add it anyways! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. When you add the `static` keyword in front of the constant, you can still access the value from `lib.c` and associated source files, but its name no longer appears in the binary's `strings` dump

**private.h**

```
#pragma once

const int MY_CONSTANT = 42;
```

Result:

```
$ strings libmylib.so | grep MY
MY_CONSTANT
MY_CONSTANT
```

With the `static` keyword:

**private.h**

```
#pragma once 

static const int MY_CONSTANT = 42;
```

Result:

```
$ strings libmylib.so | grep MY
```

In `gcc` you can also disable debugging symbols using `-g0`

Answer (score 2):

`MY_CONSTANT` is a variable which needs a place in memory. The compile linking process for C involves creating an intermediate object file before linking this into the final ELF executable. The variable needs to be tracked and have it's final address assigned and references relocated in the last stage of the link.

As an artifact of this, a symbol table is created for the object file which references `MY_CONSTANT` using it's name. By default, this isn't discarded by the linker when creating the final executable.

You can manually remove this symbol table by running `strip --strip-unneeded ./a.out`.

Note this has nothing to do with the **dynamic** symbol table which is used to link at runtime. Applications will still be able to link against and call `get_mask(void)`